# C++ Program stopped responding

Tags: c++

I have made a program that runs and I am able to enter in three variables, length, external diameter and internal diameter. After I enter in internal diameter the program freezes and a window pops up saying the program has stopped responding. The program's purpose is to calculate area, volume, mass, weight etc. of a cylindrical pipe given a number of variable inputs.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159
#define ACC_GRAVITY 9.81  /* metres/sec^2 */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE !FALSE

int main(void)
{
  /* define the required variables */

  float length;
  float ext_diam, int_diam;
  float ext_rad, int_rad;
  float volume;
  float weight;
  float area;
  float mass;
  float width;
  float flag_1, flag_2, thickness, percent;

  double no_sheets;

  /* define some constants - could use #define */

  const float density_convert = 1.0E3;
  const float mm_to_metres = 1.0E-3;
  const float density = 8.03;   /* grams per cm^3 */

  /* prompt and get values */

  printf("input the length of pipe in metres: ");
  scanf("%f", &length);

do
{
    flag_1 = FALSE;
    flag_2 = FALSE;
    printf("intput the external diameter of the pipe in milimeters: ");
    scanf("%f", &ext_diam);
    printf("ext_diam: %f\n", ext_diam);
    printf("intput the internal diameter of the pipe in milimeters: ");
    scanf("%f", int_diam);
    printf("int_diam: %f\n", int_diam);

    if (ext_diam < int_diam)
    {
        printf("external diameter must be greater than the internal diameter\n");
        flag_1 = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        percent = thickness / ext_diam * 100.0;
        if(percent > 2.5 )
        {
            /* do calculations - conversions, area of pipe cross-section, volume
            ** of pipe, mass and weight of pipe */

            ext_diam = ext_diam * mm_to_metres;
            int_diam = int_diam * mm_to_metres;
            ext_rad = ext_diam / 2.0;
            int_rad = int_diam / 2.0;

            area = (PI * ext_rad * ext_rad) - (PI * int_rad * int_rad);
            volume = area * length;

            mass = volume * density * density_convert;
            weight = mass * ACC_GRAVITY;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Width of pipe too small\n");
            flag_2 = TRUE;
        }
    }


} while(ext_diam > 0.0);

  /* output the results */

  printf("area of cylinder: %f m^2\n", area);
  printf("volume of steel needed: %f m^3\n", volume);
  printf("mass of steel needed: %f kg\n", mass);
  printf("weight of steel needed: %f newtons\n", weight);

  /* compute number of sheets of steel needed - 10m is max length of a
  ** sheet */

  no_sheets = trunc (length / 10.0) + 1;
  printf("number of 10m long sheets needed: %d\n", no_sheets);

  /* assume width of sheets is based on the average of the internal and
  ** external diameters */
  width = 2.0 * PI * (ext_rad + int_rad) / 2.0;
  printf("width of sheets: %f m\n",width);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related to the failure, but you might want to consider using `double` instead of `float` for your variables. Or even better, work in integers.

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf("%f", int_diam);`  to  `scanf("%f", &int_diam);`

Also, your `do while` loop seems to go into an infinite loop. Since it depends on the external diameter, either change the loop condition, or ensure that external diameter will reach a value <=0 inside the loop. Your `do while` loop will only terminate when user enters a non-positive value for `ext_diam`.

Also, assuming `thickness` refers to the thickness of the pipe, add this equation before you use this variable `thickness=ext_diam-int_diam;`, or any other formula you use to calculate the thickness.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed "&int_diam" and gave "thickness" an equation which I think Marco said was not initialised. I am however having trouble understanding what you mean when you say my do while loop is looping infinitely.

Comment: It doesn't actually keep looping, it's just that it won't terminate until user enters an external diameter which is non-positive.

Comment: For ex: input 1: 16,700,70; input 2: 1000,10; input 3: 0,0: output will only be for input 2, as the values calculated by input 1 are over-written, and input 3 is only there to terminate while loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

1. `scanf("%f", int_diam);`, scanf needs a pointer to the variable, this will work

   ```
   scanf("%f", &int_diam);
   ```
2. In the line

   ```
   percent = thickness / ext_diam * 100.0;
   ```

   thickness is **not** initialized the first time it is used (did you forget a passage?)

Not sure if the termination when `ext_diam` is <= 0 is intended.

Finally, there are multiple double-to-float conversions (e.g. area calculus) which might cause loss of data